# Overlay over proportionally sized background image

Tags: css

I want to show an overlay colour over a proportionally sized image, using background-size contain. My placeholder div expands correctly to the height, but not the width:

```css
.prop {
    background-image: url('http://via.placeholder.com/1600x1200');
    width:100vw;
    background-size: contain;
    height: 100vh;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;  
    border: inset 70px transparent;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.placeholder {
  background:red;
  height:100%;
  opacity:0.5;
}
```

```html
<div> 
  <div class="prop">
    
    <div class="placeholder"></div>
    
  </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Is the proportion/aspect ratio of the background image always the same? Or is it subjected to change?

Comment: yes always the same - 4:3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you mention that the aspect ratio of the image will always be 4:3 (e.g. 1600 × 1200), then there is a rather straight-forward solution: all you need is to give `.placeholder` a background image of identical aspect ratio, and position it absolutely relative to its parent `.prop`, and you're good to go.

Update your code with the following additional styles:

```
.prop {
    position: relative;
}

.placeholder {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;

    background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 4 3"><rect style="fill: red; fill-opacity: 0.5;" width="4" height="3" x="0" y="0"></rect></svg>');
    background-size: contain;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Explanation: here I have used a 4px by 3px SVG with a `<rect>` element set to have a fill of `red` and reduce the fill's opacity to `0.5`:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 4 3">
    <rect style="fill: red; fill-opacity: 0.5;" width="4" height="3" x="0" y="0"></rect>
</svg>
```

You can [use this SVG markup as part of the data URI for the `background-image` property](https://css-tricks.com/probably-dont-base64-svg/). See proof-of-concept example:

```css
.prop {
  background-image: url('http://via.placeholder.com/1600x1200');
  width: 100vw;
  background-size: contain;
  height: 100vh;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  border: inset 70px transparent;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: relative;
}

.placeholder {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  
  background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 4 3"><rect style="fill: red; fill-opacity: 0.5;" width="4" height="3" x="0" y="0"></rect></svg>');
  background-size: contain;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="prop">

    <div class="placeholder"></div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should change the `background-size:contain` to `background-size:100% 100%` like so

```css
    
        .prop {
        background-image: url('http://via.placeholder.com/1600x1200');
        background-size:100% 100%;
        background-position: center;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        border: inset 70px transparent;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        }
    
.placeholder {
      background:red;
      height:100vh;
      opacity:0.5;
      width:100%;
        }
```

```html
    
        <div> 
          <div class="prop">
            
            <div class="placeholder"></div>
            
          </div>
         </div>
```

Comment: while the overlay now fits the image - the image no longer scale proportionally...

Comment: I just made some modifications check it now

Comment: image is still distorting

Comment: I dont  see it. did you test it here??